# FT232RL VCCIO Question

Tags: ftdi

Reading the datasheet of the FT232R from FTDI did not answer my question so I'm asking here:

I have the following configuration:

```
VCC: +5V
VCCIO: +3.3V
```

The Part I'm unsure:

The datasheet of the FT232 states the following:

```
Integrated level converter on UART and CBUS
for interfacing to between +1.8V and +5V
logic.
```

and a maximum input voltage as:

```
IOmax = VCC + 0.5V
```

My question is:

Am I damaging the FT232 if my input high voltage is +5V on either RXD/TXD?
Because I think I won't because of the stated ''feature'' but I want to be sure.

[datasheet for the ft232r](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232R.pdf)

**EDIT**
If you want a reason why I'm specifically asking then: sparkfun sells these FT232 adapters which can be either 3.3V or 5V. But the only difference between the two is that either 3.3V or 5V is connected to VCCIO. Since using 3.3V on VCCIO does not affect the maximum input voltage then I would be able to use a +5V system to send and probably receive data too. This means the 3.3V version would be much more universal than the 5V version. (because I don't want to use two boards)

Comment: The correc question would be: Why is your VCCIO is 3.3V, when you are using the 5V levels?

Comment: Including a link to the datasheet of a device in the question helps folks to answer quickly. If Vcc = 5V, and IOmax = VCC + 0.5V, what is the problem you expect from driving RXD/TXD to 5V?

Comment: @gbulmer because VCCIO **is** for driving the IOs

Comment: I am not sure you will actually damage the device, but you are definitely not using it as intended.

Comment: Okay, so please answer @EugeneSh comment, "Why is your VCCIO at 3.3V?". If you drive VCCIO at 5V, all should be fine.

Comment: @gbulmer If I would do that then this question would make no sense

Comment: To clear things up: **I am not looking for a solution, I'm looking for a technical answer**

Comment: "If I would do that then this question would make no sense". There are folks who would still ask that. Okay, so please clarify that constraint in your question as "it does draw the eye".

Comment: @gbulmer what do you mean with 'it does draw the eye'?

Comment: If you want a reason why I'm specifically asking then: sparkfun sells these FT232 adapters which can be either 3.3V or 5V. But the only difference between the two is that either 3.3V or 5V is connected to VCCIO. Since using 3.3V on VCCIO does not affect the maximum input voltage then I would be able to use a +5V system to **send** and *probably* receive data too. This means the 3.3V version would be much more universal than the 5V version. (because I don't want to use two boards)

Comment: It is an unusual configuration, so it caught my attention above most other parts. So I read the question as "I would like to drive the FT232R with Vcc=5V and VCCIO=3.3V, will this be okay with 5V RXD/TXD?", but without being explicit that the voltage configuration is not open for discussion. Hence, I assume, the question from EugeneSh and my comment. Usually, I'd expect a question to be clear about that constraint. For example, it is an existing device (like an FTDI cable), where there is no room for change.

Comment: Ah, ha! That would be a great addition to your question. I can imagine lots of people might find that idea helpful, and heap kudos on you.

Comment: @gbulmer thanks for letting me know. I kinda excepted such answers but I didn't know how to correctly phrase my question. I thought it was clear enough :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dig into the datasheet and infer a few things, the "Vin" parameter doesn't change no matter what level you drive VCCIO. (See Tables 5.3 - 5.10)

This means that the input circuitry is not affected by the VCCIO level, and it only cares whether you exceed its threshold level of around 1.2V.

As the comments pointed out, it seems like an odd scenario to drive VCCIO at 3.3V (making the outputs 3.3V) while taking 5V on the input pins, but there isn't a technical problem with it.

Answer (score 2):

The datasheet does say in "Absolute Maximum Ratings",

> DC Input Voltage – USBDP and USBDM: -0.5 to +3.8V
>   DC Input Voltage –
>   High Impedance Bidirectional: -0.5 to + (VCC +0.5)
>   DC Input Voltage
>   – All Other Inputs: -0.5 to + (VCC +0.5)

RXD/TXD should be okay driven by a 5V device, they are operating below their absolute maximum.

It is common for signals to be below 5V.

What is connected to RXD/TXD?

> Voh, Output Voltage High, is only min: 2.2V, typical: 2.7V, max: 3.2V

at VCCIO=3.3V, which might have a bearing on your decision.

Edit:
Some 5V devices might like about 2.5V, so someone might get unlucky, and have a FT232R device with a minimum of 2.2V, and get unreliable results. This will likely be rare, but maybe intermittent, and hence unpleasant to debug.

I think Daniel's answer covers the input-pin case.

Comment: TXD (sending): Either a +5V device or below (3.3V, 3V or 2.8V) RXD (receiving): Nothing

Comment: So this would confirm my assumption: the FT232 accepts logic input levels from 1.8V to 5V (given VCC is 5V) but outputs only up to `VCCIO`.

Comment: Mostly agree. The small concern I have is the *minimum* Voh at 2.2V. Some 5V receivers *might* like 2.5V or more. So you might get unlucky.

Comment: Decent points about \$V_{oh}\$ vs \$V_{ih}\$ of the other device.